# How to find unused fields in a table

Tags: sql-server, linqpad

I tables that I want to remove unused fields to improve clarity and possibly to improve performance. But first I have to find out the unused fields. Any suggestions for a more elegant solution? perhaps in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the C# program in linqpad.

```
void Main()
{
    // Row count of non null fields in a table

    var l = Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel(typeof(DataContext)).GetMetaType(typeof(Briefing)).DataMembers;

    var list = new List<xfield>();
    object[] xparams = new object[0];
    foreach( var field in l.Where (x => x.DbType != null) ) {
        var sql = string.Format("SELECT count({0}) from table_name where {0} is not null", field.Name.ToLower());
        var result = ExecuteQuery<int>( sql, xparams );
        var count = result.First();
        list.Add( new xfield { name = field.Name, rows = count } );
    }   
    list.Where( e => e.rows == 0 ).Dump();
}

public class xfield
{
    public string name;
    public int rows; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no 100% sure method to discover unused columns unless you know all possible queries executed against the databases.

Here are two general things that you need to cover:

- Find all references to that table in your database (functions, stored procedures, triggers and other that are referencing this table).
- Examine all application code that is being executed and see if you can find references to that table.

Try using [ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) for database references since it’s a free tool.